# Difficulty with write.csv: no such file or directory

Tags: r, export-to-csv

So I am trying to save an altered dataset as a .csv file in R.  I am using the `write.csv` function and everything looks accurate but it says that no such directory exists.

Here is the command:

```r
write.csv(Example.raw.data,
    "C:/Users/bradenholmes/Documents/Finance363/NewRawData.csv")
```

And here is the error:

> Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) :
> cannot open the connection
> In addition: Warning message:
> In file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) :
> cannot open file 'C:/Users/bradenholmes/Documents/Finance363/NewRawData.csv': No such file or directory

Comment: What are the results if you work your way down the file path with `list.files()`, e.g. `list.files("C:/Users/bradenholmes/Documents"); list.files("C:/Users/bradenholmes/Documents/Finance363")` ? Are you considering case-sensitivity? You should also be able to use `~` (tilde) as a shortcut for your home directory, i.e. `"~/Documents/Finance363/NewRawData.csv"`

Comment: @Mako212, really?? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8425409/file-path-issues-in-r-using-windows-hex-digits-in-character-string-error